# How do I track models using other models?

Tags: php, design-patterns, models

From time to time one of my models will need to call another.  What's the best way to track this?

I was using an array in the base class of each model, so that if Model A called Model B more than once, the second and successive calls would return the existing instance, rather than loading a new one.

While this works fine for simple cases, I can see it has limitations.  For example, take the case where Model A loads Model B and Model C; then Model C needs access to Model B (or even A) - it will load the class again!

I suspect that I need a coordinating object, external to the model classes, which acts as a repository.  What patterns should I be looking at?

BTW, I am using PHP.

EDIT: Another consideration is that my views may call model methods directly too.  In these cases it would make sense to serve up an already instantiated model, rather than a new one...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) thats used in such case.

Its easy .. each model have a list with **listeners** and when something happens it says to all Listeners **hey something happend**